# building .net for 4.5 framework using 4.8 failed in docker

Tags: asp.net, docker, .net-4.5

i am trying to build the .net project.

when i use `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build`

i got this error [image]

so, the project is developed by 4.5 Framework. I can not upgrade (Businnes matter).

so i google it and found [this](https://github.com/microsoft/dotnet-framework-docker/blob/main/samples/README.md)

so i change the syntax into `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8 AS build`

now i got this [image]

i am new to docker. not know what the meaning of the error message.

Answer (score 1):

`FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build`

It means you are going to use .net core 5.0 which should be (preinstalled) in image.

So the image

`FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8 AS build`

will be deployed based on an image with preinstalled .net framework 4.8.

Unfortunately, according to this:

https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-framework-sdk/

There are versions only for 4.8 and 3.5.

I am pretty sure that update .net framework from 4.5 to 4.8 is possible.

So I would update .net framework version and use docker image for .net framework 4.8 .